# Can I redeem EUR iTunes vouchers in any EUR country?

Tags: itunes

Can I redeem a 50 EUR iTunes gift card purchased in Germany in any other country of the Euro zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can only redeem a gift card purchased in Germany in Germany. See [this Apple doc](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/de/terms.html), the section called "GESCHENKGUTSCHEINE, ITUNES KARTEN, GUTHABENKONTEN UND CONTENT CODES". 
Google translate [does a very nice job](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com%2Flegal%2Fitunes%2Fde%2Fterms.html) (the doc is in German).

Anyway, here's the (translated) quote:

> Gift certificates, iTunes Cards, Content Codes and credit accounts that were purchased in Germany can be redeemed through the stores only in Germany.

It appears that this is the case for most countries.

Comment: This makes totally sense. Countries within the EU still have different sales taxes. Since the iTunes card purchase includes the sales tax, it must be bound to a certain country.